# Javascript open/close div using onclick="showElem

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working concept of User clicks on image to display a div.

I use the `javascript:void(0);` and `onclick="showElem('div40');"` to open and close the divs

I have a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dillon/M4t5Q/

What I want is to only allow one div to be open at a time. So if one of the divs is open, it will close when another is clicked on.

I couldn't figure out a solution by myself so I would love any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide all currently open DIVs, you can use:

```
// close all other DIVs with class 'show'
var currentlyShown = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
for(var i in currentlyShown) {
    currentlyShown[i].className = 'hide';
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/M4t5Q/3/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would just be to modify `showElem` so that it closes all possibly open `div`s before opening the active one.

Comment: I am not that familiar with modifying that stuff, could you point me in a direction that would help? I appreciate it

Comment: You are closing each div now when it is clicked on the second time, so you already have the code and expertise to modify and extrapolate from.  Just add the code you would add to hide the other elements before you display the present element.